# Javascript hide/show classes with checkbox

Tags: javascript

I am just learning javascript, so please bear with me!

I want to be able to use checkboxes to choose to hide/show div classes (to basically filter the amount of info being shown). It is done in [this](http://www.askthecssguy.com/2009/03/checkbox_filters_with_jquery_1.html)... but I'm try to figure out something much simpler (since I don't need to dynamically generate the checkbox options.)

I came across this example: The Javascript:

```
 function showMe (it, box) { 
   var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 
   document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
 }
```

The HTML

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="value1" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" />value1
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="value2" onclick="showMe('div2', this)" />value2
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="value3" onclick="showMe('div3', this)" />value3
</form>

<div id="div1" style="display:block">Show Div 1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:block">Show Div 2</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:block">Show Div 3</div>

</body>

</html>
```

But it only works for div ids, not classes. Any idea on how I can work this?

Thanks in advance if you can help me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, you're probably best off using a library like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or similar for this sort of thing, as standardization for finding elements by class name (the `document.getElementsByClassName` method) is relatively recent and it's not supported yet by at least one major browser (they [document a way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282900(VS.85).aspx) to add it, but not a very good one).

In Prototype, the `$$` function searches by a large subset of [the CSS3 selectors draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/) proposed recommendation. In jQuery, the `$` function does much the same thing (via the [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) selector engine, which can also be used on its own, weparate from jQuery).

In Prototype, you can show or hide elements by class like so:

```
$$('div.myClassName').invoke('hide'); // Hides all matches
$$('div.myClassName').invoke('show'); // Shows all matches
```

In jQuery, it's:

```
$('div.myClassName').hide(); // Hides all matches
$('div.myClassName').show(); // Shows all matches
```

Comment: @David: LOL, was just adding those (and Closure and Sizzle)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Double LOL, I was writing a very similar response when yours popped up. I removed mine and I felt I had to add the only thing that differed between mine and yours.

Comment: Ekk... I've been terrified of trying out jquery, but it only took 20 minutes to get it working perfectly. Amazing. Thank you guys!

Comment: Microsoft's `getElementsByClassName`-for-IE code isn't very good. It only works on IE8, it fails for class names containing punctuation, and it (utterly bizarrely) uses slow multiple passes/selectors when it could all be done in one. Avoid. (And like all `getElementsByClassname` fallback code, it of course returns a static NodeList not a live one.)

Comment: @Bob: Oh, I didn't mean to imply that that M$ hack was any *good*. Just that they document a way to add it. Why the *heck* it isn't just implemented (preferably better than in that code!) I couldn't tell you...